# How to jump focus on textfields from one to next in Material-Ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am not able to get how to jump focus in material-ui components automatically when it reach its maxlength(eg:like in otp fields).

Comment: jump focus by  tab? tab-index="1" would be first tab and go on.

Comment: Thanks roy, but i forgot to mention i need solution based on maxlength, whenever textfield value reaches maxlength it jumps it's focus to next field in material-ui textfield components.

Comment: Please, provide us some of your code (HTML and JS)and test case.